# Changes in database configuration do not take effect

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

In laravel 5, I created Middleware that changes the database credentials:

```
config([
    'database.connections.mysql.database' => 'someDB',
    'database.connections.mysql.username' => 'someUser',
    'database.connections.mysql.password' => 'somePass'
]);
```

Using a route that makes use of the middleware, I tried to output the current database within the controller:

```
exit(config('database.connections.mysql.database'));
```

The information is correctly set to `'someDB'`.
When I use eloquent in the same function it tries to contact the 'old' database and not the `'someDB'` settings I've set in the middleware.

Any thoughts about this?

Comment: I believe when you set the config it should contain a multidimensional array, and when you retrieve then yes you can use dot notation.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by just creating a new connection:

```
config([
    'database.connections.mysql2.database' => 'someDB',
    'database.connections.mysql2.username' => 'someUser',
    'database.connections.mysql2.password' => 'somePass',
    'database.connections.mysql2.driver' => 'mysql',
    'database.connections.mysql2.host' => 'localhost',

    .....

    // setting default connection to mysql2
    'database.default' => 'mysql2',
]);
```